# How do I abruptly stop a thread currently executing in the background?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, while-loop

**FACTS:**

I have a method executing on a background thread :

```
[currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playOn:) withObject:self];
```

This method basically contains a while loop that keeps on executing until the user clicks on a *Quit* button:

```
-(void) playOn: (UIViewController*) thisViewController
{
    while(!quitButtonPressed)
    {
       // this is my method's main loop
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

> If the user clicks on Quit somewhere in the middle of the above loop
>   *the rest* of the loop would have to execute *before* it checks the BOOL once again and eventually stops. In order to prevent that from
>   happening and have the while-loop stop *as soon as* the user clicks on
>   Quit, I guess I could also add *many* `if(quitButtonPressed) break;`
>   *here and there* in my while loop in order to *semi-constantly* check and *"immediately"* break away if needed. However, this doesn't seem
>   very clever or practical from a design perspective given the *size* of
>   the above main while-loop and the fact that it contains *many smaller
>   while-loops* inside of it (the number of `if.. break;` I would have to
>   add would be quite big and could make things quite complicated to
>   figure out..)

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION** (but is it the right one?) **:**

> So I was thinking that the best way would be to stop/cancel the
>   background thread on which the above method's while loop is executing,
>   instead of the while-loop itself, inside the method, the moment the
>   user clicks on *Quit*
>
> Is this, or something similar (i.e. a better suggestion), possible and
>   how exactly could I do this?

**POSSIBLE IMPLEMENTATION OF ABOVE SOLUTION:**

I could create this new method:

```
-(void)checkQuitButton
{
   while(!quitButtonPressed)
   {
      //wait
   }
   if(quitButtonPressed)
   {
     // stop this thread-->[currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playOn:) withObject:self];
     // this is the method I'm looking for
   }
}
```

And then I could start executing the above and my previous main method concurrently on two separate background threads as follows:

```
[currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playOn:) withObject:self];
[currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(checkQuitButton) withObject:nil];
```

While the *game* while-loop is being executed *another* while-loop is checking the QuitButton at the same time. But is there a method that I can actually call in order to cancel what was started here:

```
[currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playOn:) withObject:self];
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct solution is to periodically check for a "stop" flag. Abruptly terminating a thread provides no opportunity to clean up resources. In short, you would leak memory terribly.

But the deeper issue is that you almost certainly should not have this kind of thread. It strongly suggests an incorrect design. In iOS, most background operations should take the form of focused operations, implemented either with `NSOperation` or blocks with Grand Central Dispatch. You should very, very seldom need a long lived thread that is performing many different kinds of functions. Within your operation, it should be fairly straightforward where to put the "check for cancel" statements.

There is also almost no case where you should use `performSelectorInBackground:`. It is an incredibly dangerous method that gives you very little control. Instead, read the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for guidance on how to properly implement background operations. Pay special attention to the section "Migrating Away From Threads."

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. I can't really see why running the above method on a background thread can be incredibly dangerous but I'll trust your experience. :) I'll look into operations and try out the migration..

Comment: `performSelectorInBackground:` is a common source of serious bugs. It's very easy to accidentally spawn many more threads than you mean since there is no easy way to determine with it that you have already spawned this thread, nor do you have a good way to call methods on the thread. When creating threads by hand, you generally should create an `NSThread` object and put it in an ivar so you can use `performSelector:withObject:onThread:`. But again, this is very rare since the creation of Grand Central Dispatch.